# How to make Where lambda to search from a List?

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

I would like to search files passing multiple file extensions but I would like to send it in a list.

How can I approach this in a clean way?

```
//I wanna pass my list to the Where method
List<string> fileExtensionList

//this works fine
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\path", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".jpg") || s.EndsWith(".png"));
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although you can use `EndsWith` to check extensions, there are more appropriate methods that lead to simpler code:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\path", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Where(s => fileExtensionList.Contains(Path.GetExtension(s)));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
List<string> fileExtensionList = ...

var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\path", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(fileName => fileExtensionList.Any(extension => fileName.EndsWith(extension)));
```

`Any` is an extension method for collections. It returns `true` if any item in collection matches your condition.